# Where to put the _DB_Prefix_ and the $id_manufacturer?

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I've the following code:

```
$query = "UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'specific_price` sp SET sp.`from`=NOW(), sp.`to`=DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 19 HOUR)
INNER JOIN  `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p ON (sp.id_product = p.id_product)
WHERE p.`id_manufacturer` = '.(int)$id_manufacturer";
//Run the Query
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
```

I know I have to modify the location and usage of _DB_PREFIX And $id_manufacturer but where and how? 
I admit that I'm quite lost right now and some help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// define variable for database prefix
// you can also use simple php variable here instead of using constant
define(_DB_PREFIX_, "database-name");

// filter data
$id_manufacturer = (int)$id_manufacturer;

// prepare query
$query = "UPDATE "._DB_PREFIX_."specific_price sp 
            SET sp.`from`=NOW(), sp.`to`=DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 19 HOUR)
            INNER JOIN "._DB_PREFIX_."product p USING id_product
            WHERE p.id_manufacturer = $id_manufacturer";

//Run the Query
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

**Note:** Do NOT use above mentioned code in any production system. Please consider this just as tutorial. Its very high time to start using PDO or mysqli. You can google it and get more information about it.